# Byte[32] to NSString and back

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, arrays

I've been trying to save my Byte[32] in a database and wanted to convert it into a NSString first. But I just can't find a way to convert it into a NSString and back without running into errors.

```
Byte test[32];
test[0] &= 248;
test[31] &= 127;
test[31] |= 64;

//Curve25519 ECDH Key arrangement 
static const uint8_t basepoint[32] = {9};
Byte mypublic[32];
curve25519_donna(mypublic, test, basepoint);

const unsigned char *bytearray = test;
NSString *secStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:bytearray length:sizeof(test) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSData *bytes = [secStr dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
memcpy(test, [bytes bytes], sizeof(test));
```

But this doesn't work and its difficult, because I need the Byte[32].

Thank you :)
Anton

Comment: Why are you trying to convert arbitrary bytes into a string? That's not valid.

Comment: In order to convert a byte array to a string it's necessary to know the character encoding of the bytes.  Furthermore, `sizeof(bytearray) ` gives you the size of a pointer, not the size of the array.

Comment: It sounds like what you're looking for is Base64 encoding.

Comment: @HotLicks Actually, in this case he's taking sizeof of an array, so he will actually get the number of bytes in the array.  If test was declared as `Byte *test;` then your observation would be correct.  As it would if he were taking `sizeof(bytearray)`

Comment: @David - If you look at my original comment and the edits you will see that he was doing `sizeof(bytearray)`.

Comment: @HotLicks so he was, the perils of edits :)